# How to use filter in python to filter a dictionary in this situation?

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I never used python before. Now I have a dictionary like :

```
d1 = {1:2,3:3,2:2,4:2,5:2}
```

The pair[0] in each pair means point, the pair[1] in each pair means the cluster id. So d1 means point 1 belongs to cluster 2, point 3 belongs to cluster 3, point 2 belongs to cluster 2, point 4 belongs to cluster 2, point 5 belongs to cluster 2. No point belongs to cluster 1.
How to use filter(don't use loop) to get a dictionary like following :

```
d2 = {1:[],2:[1,2,4,5],3:[3]}
```

it means no point belongs to cluster 1, 1,2,4,5 belongs to cluster 2, 3 belongs to cluster 3.
I tried :

```
d2 = dict(filter(lambda a,b: a,b if a[1] == b[1] , d1.items()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

d2 = defaultdict(list)
for point, cluster in d1.items():
    d2[cluster].append(point)
```

Your `defaultdict` won't have a cluster `1` in it, but if you know what clusters you expect, then all will be fine with the world (because the empty list will be put in that slot when you try to look there -- this is the "default" part of the `defaultdict`):

```
expected_clusters = [1, 2, 3]
for cluster in expected_clusters:
    print(d2[cluster])
```

---

FWIW, doing this problem with the builtin `filter` is just insanity.  However, if you must, something like the following works:

```
d2 = {}
filter(lambda (pt, cl): d2.setdefault(cl, []).append(pt), d1.items())
```

Note that I'm using python2.x's unpacking of arguments.  For python3.x, you'd need to do something like `lambda item: d2.setdefault(item[1], []).append(item[0])`, or, maybe we could do something like this which is a bit nicer:

```
d2 = {}
filter(lambda pt: d2.setdefault(d1[pt], []).append(pt), d1)
```

We can do a *tiny bit* better with the `reduce` builtin (at least the `reduce` isn't simply a vehicle to create an implicit loop and therefore actually *returns* the dict we want):

```
>>> d1 = {1:2,3:3,2:2,4:2,5:2}
>>> reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(d1[k], []).append(k) or d, d1, {})
{2: [1, 2, 4, 5], 3: [3]}
```

But this is still *really* ugly python.

Comment: we cannot use loop in this problem.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  I missed that.  Well, it is possible (I've just done it in my terminal) -- but that constraint makes this smell a whole lot more like a homework problem (and a poorly designed one at that) where I don't want to just hand you an answer.  When doing this, it seemed that `filter` was really just a vehicle to loop over the items.  What attempts have you made?  If we can see that and where you're stuck, then perhaps we can take a look and help guide you to an acceptable solution.

Comment: I tried. But I am very confused with how to compare the pair[1] in different pair in a dictionary with filter. I just post my try case. But since I never used python before, it has some syntax errors.

Comment: How to compare the pair[1] in each pair in a dictionary ?

Comment: @LiyuanLiu -- I've added a few options, but none of them are any good.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d1 = {1:2,3:3,2:2,4:2,5:2}
>>> dict(map(lambda c : (c, [k for k, v in d1.items() if v == c]), d1.values()))
{2: [1, 2, 4, 5], 3: [3]}
```

1. lambda function to get the value list
2. map function to map values(clusters) using the above lambda